# $xy'+(2x^2-2)\cot(y)=0$ find $\cos(y(x))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$xy'+(2x^2-2)\cot(y)=0$ is an ordinary differential equation.

Find $\cos(y(x))$ (implicit presentation) when $y(1)=\frac{-\pi}{3}$.

$xy'+(2x^2-2)\cot(y)=0 \implies \dfrac{1}{\cot(y)}\,y'=-\dfrac{(2x^2-2)}{x}$

$\displaystyle\int \frac{dy}{\cot(y)}=\int \frac{(2x^2-2)}{x}\,dx \implies -\ln|\cos y|=-x^2+2\ln|x|+C.$

$y(1)=\dfrac{-\pi}{3} \implies C=\ln(2)+1$

$\cos(y)=e^{x^2-2\ln x-\ln(2)-1}$

Then $\cos(y)=e^{x^2-2\ln x-\ln(2)-1}$

I cant see why I'm wrong?

Comment: Why to you think this is wrong? You could extract $e^{-2\ln x-\ln 2}=\frac1{2x^2}$.

Comment: Its my homework I insert this $\exp \left(x^2-2\ln x-\ln \left(2\right)-1\right)$ and it tells me , "The domain of your function doesn't match that of the correct answer", maybe I was supposed to write $ln|x|$?

Comment: That you have to try out. As the equation is not an ODE at $x=0$, the domain of the solution has to be a subset of $(0,\infty)$ (per the initial point) anyway, so that the absolute value should not be necessary.